# Autorun.inf | mention full path to icon file

Tags: icons, autorun

I'm trying to set an .ico file as my USB flash drive icon.

Icon is located at this path:

C:\Users\Ahsan\Pictures\gear.ico

What i want is:
when the USB is connected to my laptop (running windows 10), it may automatically pick up the icon from the above mentioned path.

---

My autorun.inf code:

[AutoRun]

ICON="%SystemDrive%\%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\gear.ico"

LABEL=MyUSB

Result:
Label gets changed by this autorun file, but the icon is not getting changed.

---

Another attempt

[AutoRun]

ICON="C:\Users\Ahsan\Pictures\gear.ico"

LABEL=MyUSB

Result:
Again the label changes to MyUSB, but the icon is not changing.

---

I just don't know, how to properly mention the path to that icon file which is placed in C: drive.

I shall be VERY THANKFUL if somebody please help me with my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icon's file must be in the same directory as the file specified. The solution is to locate the icon file on your USB drive

Comment: Yes, i am able to achieve this: when both the icon and autorun file are in the same drive, the icon works.

I thought there might be a way to access the icon from other drives as well.

Thank you so much for the response.